# Google Apps Authentication for a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openid, google-apps

I'm currently using Authlogic to handle all user accounts, but our company has switched over to Google apps and I would much rather use that same authentication for all users.

My question is - how?

I know I'll need the ruby-openid gem but I have yet to integrate authentication with a 3rd party. Any recent examples or tutorials out there to help guide the way?

Thanks!

Comment: I ended up going with a crude but simple solution.  Since every account would have to be an active email from our Google Apps Domain I left authlogic behind and did a simple open-id authentication with the  open-id url hard coded to our domain.  I then just get back the identity url and based on that look up an existing user record or create a new one.  Not sure if it's the best way to do it but it works and seems to be pretty secure.

What helped?
- open_id_authentication plugin
- http://toddsedano.blogspot.com/2010/05/integrating-openid-google-apps-and-ruby.html

Comment: Again, I am not using AuthLogic but will mark this as answered.  If you're having the same issues visit http://toddsedano.blogspot.com/2010/05/integrating-openid-google-apps-and-ruby.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good resource [here](http://github.com/benaldred/authlogic-google-account-oauth) that I've used to get this working in the past.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you are looking for: [authlogic_openid_selector_example](http://github.com/shripadk/authlogic_openid_selector_example). It isn't a tutorial but you can have a look at the code.

Answer (score 1):

Seth Ladd, a Google developer advocates, has a blog post on how to authenticate [using a google account in a rails 3 appl](http://blog.sethladd.com/2010/09/ruby-rails-openid-and-google.html). You may need to change the example depending on how google apps is configured in your company.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought -- [RPX](https://rpxnow.com/) has the ability to do logins from google, and you could use the [Authlogic RPX plugin](http://github.com/tardate/rails-authlogic-rpx-sample)